# Why getting Image path not Image in Modal pop up after form submission in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to display Image in modal pop up after form submission. But currently, I am getting the path C:\fakepath\Flag.jpg, not the Image. And also When I edit my form,  I am not getting the Image.

Can anyone please suggest me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult _Edit(ClsEmployee clsEmployee, HttpPostedFileBase FilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    FilePath = Request.Files[0];

                    if (FilePath != null && FilePath.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath.FileName);
                        string path = "/Image/" + fileName;
                        clsEmployee.FilePath = path;

                    }
                }
                context.Entry(clsEmployee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();           
                return Json(new { success = true });                
            }
            catch
            {              
               return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }
```

Custom Image Helper

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string height, string width, params string[] allClasses)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));//throws error
    tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
    {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
            value.AppendFormat("height:{0};", height);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
            value.AppendFormat("width:{0};", width);

        tb.Attributes.Add("style", value.ToString());
    }
    if (allClasses?.Any() ?? false)
        tb.Attributes.Add("class", string.Join(" ", allClasses));

    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

View

```
    <tr>
    <td class="Title">
        @item.Title
    </td>
    <td class="Link">
        @item.Link
    </td>

    <td class="filePath">
    <a target="_blank" data-id="@item.FilePath" href=@item.FilePath >   
    @Html.Image(item.FilePath, "Image", "60px", "", "img-thumbnail")
     </a>
    </td>
 <td>
  <a class="mdlEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">Edit</a>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Partial View Modal

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("_Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "Editform", enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditRecord" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                                                  
                  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)                                                                                                                            
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)                                                                     
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Link)                                         
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilePath, new { type = "file"})                          

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Script to show existing data into modal

```
   var row;
    $(document).on('click', '.mdlEdit', function () {
        row = $(this).closest('tr');   
        var title = $.trim(row.find('.Title').text());
        var link = $.trim(row.find('.Link').text());
        var filepath = $(this).data("Id");    
        $('#Title').val(title);
        $('#Link').val(link);
        $('#FilePath').attr('src', filepath);

    })
```

Script to Submit the form

```
 $('#Editform').submit(function () {
var formdata = new FormData($('#Editform').get(0));
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("_Edit", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
           row.find('.Title').text($('#Title').val());
            row.find('.Link').text($('#Link').val());
            row.find('.filePath').text($('#FilePath').val());
            $('#Editform').get(0).reset();
            $('#EditRecord').modal('hide');
        }
    }
    });
return false;
})
```

Comment: `$('Editform').get(0)` You seem to have missed a `#` or `.` selector there. Alternatively you could just use `new FormData(this);` as the `submit` handler is already in scope of the `form`

Comment: `$('#FilePath').attr('src', filepath);` makes no sense. Your element with `id="FilePath"` is a `file input and you cannot set the value of a file input programatically. In anycase, an input does not have a `src` attribute, and `filepath` is undefined since your `<a class="mdlEdit" .. >` element does not have a `data-id` attribute

Comment: And to update the `src` attribute of the `<img>`, you need to get the path that the file was saved on the server (i.e. your `_Edit` method needs to return that path in the `JsonResult`. And in any case, your element with `class="filePath"` is a `<td>`, not the `<img>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your code. The first thing you should be doing is using a view model, not a data model in the view, and it will contain a `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }` property in addition to your `string FilePath` property (refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)).

Your file input will then be generated using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file"})`, and the `HttpPostedFileBase FilePath` parameter is not required in your POST method.

Next, in your script to show existing data into modal, you can delete the `var filepath = $(this).data("Id");` and `$('#FilePath').attr('src', filepath);`. You cannot set the value of a file input programatically for security reasons (it can only be set by the user selecting a file in the browser), and in any case the value of `filepath` will be `undefined` because the element does not have a `data-Id` attribute, and an `<input>` does not have a `src` attribute.

The main issue with displaying you image is that you need to set the `src` attribute the the path that you saved the file on the server, so that you need to return that path in your `JsonResult`. Currently your not even saving the file to the server. Modify the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _Edit(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        ClsEmployee employee = .... // you code to get the data model from the database based on the ID
        if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);
            string path = "/Image/" + fileName;
            model.File.SaveAs(path);
            employee.FilePath = path;
        }
        .... // map other properties from the view model to the data model - e.g.
        employee.Title = model.Title; // etc.
        context.SaveChanges();           
        return Json(new { success = true , filePath = employee.FilePath }); // include the file path in the JsonResult     
    }
    catch
    {              
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

Then modify the script to set the `src` attribute to the path returned by the controller method

```
$('#Editform').submit(function () {
    var formdata = new FormData($('#Editform').get(0));
    $.ajax({
        .... // as before
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                row.find('.Title').text($('#Title').val());
                row.find('.Link').text($('#Link').val());
                row.find('.filePath').find('img').attr('src', response.FilePath); // modify this
                $('#Editform').get(0).reset();
                $('#EditRecord').modal('hide');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```